# IfDefine and RewriteBase doesn't work well together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ifdefine

When I use this code, it works just okay:

```
<IfDefine ${ServerBase}>
    RewriteBase ${ServerBase}
</IfDefine>
```

But when I add this, it always uses `RewriteBase \` which was not what I want.

```
<IfDefine !${ServerBase}>
    RewriteBase /
</IfDefine>
```

The condition was already different. One of them when ServerBase is defined and one of them is when ServerBase is NOT defined. How can I use IfDefine else pattern with RewriteBase?

Answer (score 0):

`IfDefine` checks whether a parameter is defined or not. It doesn't check it's value.

You need to use it as:

```
<IfDefine ServerBase>
    RewriteBase ${ServerBase}
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine !ServerBase>
    RewriteBase /
</IfDefine>
```

Note use of `ServerBase` instead of `${ServerBase}`.

[Check official Apache doc of `IfDefine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifdefine)

Comment: How are you testing it? Can you show full code in your question?

Comment: Hmmmm, I get this error `[Tue Dec 11 16:09:05.587936 2018] [core:alert] [pid 19988:tid 1984] [client ::1:55876] D:/htdocs/myproject/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL`. Does that help?

Comment: I have provided full code that is working fine on my local Apache